# Substitution in the taylor series of $\ln(1+ x)$

Tags: calculus, summation, taylor-expansion

We know that $$\ln(1+ x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}$$
I need to find the Maclaurin series for $\ln(4 - x)$. The approach I have tried is writing $\ln(4 - x)$ as $\ln(1 + (3 - x))$ and then substituting $3-x$ in $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n} \rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(3-x)^n}{n}$$

Is this a correct approach, since the answer in the textbook I am referring to uses derivatives to find the series.

Comment: Maclaurin series means the series must be centred at $0$. The one you are getting is centred at $3$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Oh, so is there no other way to solve this other than using derivatives?

Comment: Hint:   $\ln(4-x) = \ln4 + \ln(1-x/4)$.

Comment: @irchans Oh I get it now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\log(4-x)=\log(4)+\log \left(1-\frac{x}{4}\right)$$ So, use you expression for $\log(1-t)$ and replace $t$ by $\frac x4$.

Answer (score 0):

You are also right but your series will be valid only for
$$|3-x|<1 \implies -1<3-x <1 \implies 2<x< 4.$$
Your's is a Taylor series about $x=3$, which can also be found as usual by finding
various derivatives of $\log(4-x)$ at $x=3$.
Series suggested by @Claude Lebovici is the actual Maclaurin series which is also a Taylor-series about $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but could you tell me how do you get the condition $|3−x|<1$?

Comment: @Aaditya Dhruv, Because the used  expansion  $\ln(1+z)$  is valid only when $|z|<1.$.